# Converting Spring integration xml to Java DSL - Invoke method in Inbound Channel adapter

Tags: java, xml, spring-integration-dsl

I have a xml as follows :

```
    <int:inbound-channel-adapter id="tasksForResendingToAggregatorPoller" ref="taskProcessor"
                                 method="getTaskIdForResendingToAggregator"
                                 channel="resultAggregationChannel" auto-startup="false">
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="-1" fixed-delay="#{1 * T(org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils).MILLIS_PER_HOUR}" receive-timeout="-1"/>
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="resultAggregationChannel" datatype="java.lang.Long">
        <int:queue capacity="${maxNumberOfMessagesInBuffers}"/>
    </int:channel>
```

How do I change this to Java DSL? I have tried below code but its incomplete. Im not sure how to add the 'ref' and 'method' attribute.

```
@Bean(name= PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
        return Pollers.fixedDelay(DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_HOUR).receiveTimeout(-1).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel resultAggregationChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.queue(bceMaxNumberOfMessagesInBuffers).get();
    }
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow taskAgregator() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("resultAggregationChannel")
                .handle(getEnrichmentTaskIdForResendingToAggregator)
                .get();

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
IntegrationFlows.from(() -> bean.method(), e -> e.poller(...))
    .handle(...)
    ...
```

It doesn't make sense to use a queue channel there.